# Symfony2 - Sonata Admin - add javascript before field

Tags: javascript, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

In admin class:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'text')
    ;
}
```

I don't know how I can before "name" add javascript, can you help me?

Comment: Do you need to add javascript for a specific field (`name` field in this case)? Can you tell me more about what do you want to do?

Comment: I want create autocomplete name from ajax.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what to answer. Hold on for a minute, I'm writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Working for me:**

In admin class **src\PP\TestBundle\TestAdmin.php**

```
public function configure() {
    $this->setTemplate('edit', 'PPTestBundle:CRUD:edit_javascript.html.twig');
}
```

In **src\PP\TestBundle\Resources\views\edit_javascript.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/pptest/admin/js/myscripts.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When you do all this stuff and you have upload myscripts.js you should send this in command line:

```
app/console assets:install web
```

*(possible that I forgot something)*

Sorry for my bad English :<>

Comment: If you need to install assets from the bundle, use `app/console assets:install web --symlink` instead, to avoid copying the resources...

Comment: `setTemplate` can also be called using the service configuration as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates)

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED**

**1º** You need to create a custom TWIG template for it (where you could place your javascript code just before the widget code).

**2º** Then you write inside `ap/config/config.yml` where your custom template is to allow Symfony and SonataAdmin to recognize it.

**1º** You have some info here [Sonata Admin - Custom template](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template)

**2º** More info here [customize field types](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html)

An example could be something like this:

**Admin class**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'ajax_autocomplete')
            ->add('description', 'text')
    ;
}
```

And, in the TWIG template you need to extend from the Sonata Admin field template that better fits your necessities. In this case maybe `base_edit.html.twig` or `edit_text.html.twig`

You have a list of templates to extend from, inside this Sonata Admin dir: `vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Sonata\AdminBundle\Resources\views\CRUD`

**Customization**

Imagine you have placed your custom template inside `XXXBundle:YYY:ajax_autocomplete.html.twig`

I think it should work if you write a line here:

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
        types:
            list:
                ajax_autocomplete: XXXBundle:YYY:ajax_autocomplete.html.twig
```

Comment: Yea but, now shows error: The option "template" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize" (...)

Comment: It's means that: We can't use custom template in create/edit page.             ##EDIT## Maybe I should use filter?

Comment: Now I have an error: Could not load type "ajax_autocomplete". 
It works as I add in "configureListFields", but does not work in method "configureFormFields" where it is needed.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, you don't have to add it to the `sonata_doctrine_orm_admin` config at `/app/config/config.yml`. Why? Because is not related to Sonata Admin, but Symfony2. Read the following documentation, please: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: Have you tried the solution from the documentation (the comment above this)? I'm interested on it.

Comment: Yes, I tested it and this not working, because in your code ->> ***list:*** <-- this is only for showing list and I need this in edit... I have already, later I will send working code.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from sonata admin `3.x` you can add/remove js/css to/from the page without extending it.

```
sonata_admin:
    ....
    assets:
        # javascript paths to add to the page in addition to the list above
        extra_javascripts:
            - 'your js file path'
        # javascript paths to remove from the page
        remove_javascripts: 
            - 'your js file path'
```

you can find more information here https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/4836/files?short_path=e252be0#diff-e252be027e26148c11d971dc969f4be0